# Visual Studio InstallShield Project building error about localized resources

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localization, setup-project, building, installshield-2012

I created an **InstallShield** setup project in Visual Studio 2012. In the **Application Files** section of **Project Assistan**, I added **"Primary output"** and **"Localized resources"** files by using **Add Project Outputs** button after that completed all other sections. When I trying to build setup project, I'm getting an error like below.

**Could not resolve Visual Studio .NET project output '{ProjectName}.Localized resources' from component {ProjectName}.Localized_resources**

I have three different projects in my solution and I have got this error for two projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no any localized resource in a project, InstallShield gives this error. **To avoid this error** (*maybe you will complete all resources localization when project completed but you need to setup now*) **and complete setup project building, at least one resource file must be localized in project**.